# stop loss / close at hit the ema50 direcly and not wait for candle finish

Tags: pine-script

I use

```
   if ta.crossover(close, ema50)
       strategy.close
       ...
```

works so far.

The candle goes trough ema and after the candle is finished the strategy goes out.

But i dont want to wait for the candle finish, the strategy close should be triggered directly by hitting the line of ema. not wait for candleclosing.

how do i do this?

Answer (score 0):

`strategy.close()` will place a market order - meaning it will wait till bar is closed.

You can use `strategy.exit()` set a stop loss at your EMA's value.

Something like below:

```
strategy.exit("Long Exit", "Long", stop=ema_value)
```

Please note that, this will use EMA's value on the previous bar.